# Ideas for questions we can answer using data given.

Tags: statistics

[image]

v. What are some of the questions we can answer using this data?

We can try to answer questions like,

What is the average score obtained by the 10 students?

How many have obtained A's and how many have obtained F grades?

Could I get some more ideas for question 5. I got the first 4 done just need some cool questions to ask to really make it stand out.

Comment: You can ask whether there is a clear correlation between the grade they got in the course with the score they get on the SAT, further being able then to predict what score someone got on the SAT if you're given their grade and vice versa.  The sample size is far too small to have very much confidence in the predictions however.  See for instance [linear regression on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just had a follow up question...for iii would the population be the total number of students who have taken SAT tests? Then the sample would be 10 for iv.

Comment: It is unclear what the actual population is.  We might be talking specifically about children of members of the board of trustees.  We could be talking about students in Atlanta.  We could be talking about students across all of the United States.  In any case, the population is the *set* of students we are interested in who have taken the SAT and whatever course the grade is from.  The population *size* is the number of such students.